# Map a double dead key to grave accent

Tags: keyboard, karabiner

I am trying to emulate the Windows behaviour of getting a grave accent by inputting two ´ dead keys, so the rule should remap:

´´ -> `

Here is my attempt that is not working because `from` is not an object:

```
{
  "title": "Double dead key to grave accent",
  "rules": [
    {
      "description": "",
      "manipulators": [
        {
          "type": "basic",
          "from": [
            {
              "modifiers": {
                "mandatory": [
                  "left_alt"
                ]
              },
              "key_code": "e"
            },
            {
              "modifiers": {
                "mandatory": [
                  "left_alt"
                ]
              },
              "key_code": "e"
            }
          ],
          "to": [
            {
              "repeat": false,
              "key_code": "grave_accent_and_tilde"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I am using a Windows UK extended layout keyboard

Comment: If you have a UK keyboard, then the grave accent is already on the key left of Z. [Most people think of it as a backtick, but typographically it's a grave.] You don't need any special tricks to generate it. If you want to add it to a letter, you type alt/grave then letter to get à rather than just `

Comment: There is no grave accent on the key left of Z. My layout is this one https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/da/KB_United_Kingdom.svg/400px-KB_United_Kingdom.svg.png

Comment: Then you have your keyboard input set to British PC rather than British, & the grave moves up to left of 1. [That affects adding a grave to a letter, the dead key stays in the same place as British physically, ie, left of Z, so visually it becomes alt backslash \ instead] Personally, if I have to use a PC keyboard, I keep it set at British & ignore what it says on the keys - it's just easier for me that way.

Comment: @TomGewecke usually I make the grave accent by pressing `+Space but it is a dead key by default on Windows using the extended UK keyboard layout

Comment: Now you should get grave accent by just pressing the key under escape.  Isn't that easier?

Comment: Yes but I am using it as a dead key with karabiner so now I cannot type the grave accent

Comment: But why are you making up your own dead keys when the Mac already has lots of them, ready-made & not falling over each other?

Comment: Are you basically trying to duplicate this layout but for Mac?   http://kbdlayout.info/kbdukx/   Ukelele would be a good tool for that.

Comment: @TomGewecke could you help me understand how to install that linked layout in Ukulele please?

Comment: The linked layout is only for Windows.  You have to recreate it for Mac with https://software.sil.org/ukelele/  unless you can find it already made for you by someone on the internet